# CSS: Background image not showing in print preview even when configured to show

Tags: css, printing, background-image, print-preview

In Chrome's and Firefox's print preview I've toggled 'Show background colours and images' and I can see simple coloured backgrounds switch on and off but there's a background image that doesn't display at all. It shows up ok when the page is rendered normally in the browser. Why isn't it appearing?

Comment: Is there a print media specific style sheet in the page of interest?

Comment: Yes. It overrides the background image url.

Comment: ... and the override works when I switch the print CSS media type to screen and view it in the browser. Additionally, there are other things such as hiding other images that the print CSS is doing correctly in the print preview.

Answer (score 0):

If the page has a print media specific style sheet that sets the background image to none, then the browser will not print out the image.

Comment: It doesn't set it to none. It sets it to a different image.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page of interest? I can look at it later and try to figure it out.

Comment: Its private so I will create a mock up.